# Having a basic issue using merge function

Tags: r, merge, match

I'm having a problem with merge()

I have two data frames, one that I imported from SPSS (ssfia) and one that I created on my own. The latter contains a variable indexing the degree of overlap between two variables in the former.

`match<-ifelse(ssfia$Func_Source==ssfia$Symptom_Source,1,0)`

I want to merge this new "match" variable by "ID" the SPSS dataset (ssfia), so I made a data frame with ID and my new Match variable.

`matchf<-data.frame(match,ssfia$ID)`

Now I try to merge them...

`merge(ssfia,matchf,by="ID")`

And it gives me the following error:

`Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid column(s)`

I tried searching this site for similar problems, but everyone else seems to have a more nuanced issue. I'm guessing this will be something pretty simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the names of `matchf`?  The error suggests there does not exist such a column as `ID` in `matchf`.

Comment: excellent! for some reason the levels are: (match) and (ssfia.ID), instead of (match) and (ID). The code is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, that column probably doesn't exist in `matchf`. Try:

```
matchf <- data.frame(match, ID=ssfia$ID)
```

Then re-run the merge.