# Restructuring a data frame for 3D plots in R

Tags: r, dataframe, scatter-plot

I realize often times that 3D plots are not the most efficient way to present a set of data, but previous 2D plots I've made for a particular dataset seem to indicate that a 3D plot would help to break the information into more distinct clusters for analysis. That being said, I've never done this in R and I'm having trouble restructuring my data frame before making a 3D scatterplot using plot3d().

At the moment, my data frame has 2 columns and a few thousand rows of information. Column one is an identifier, A,B,C... and Column 2 is one measured feature for that identifier.

Ex

```
ID Area 
A   1.2
A   3.0
A   2.7
B   1.4
B   2.5
C   4.3
C   2.1
C   1.7
```

I will plot the area on the Y axis. Using a function like table(), I can get the number of times A, B, or C occur: (A=3,B=2,C=3) and this value will become the x coordinate for all the IDs with that result. But what I would like to do is have that information also put into a third column that assigns a unique z for the given x coordinate. In other words, Z should represent how many times a given X has shown up, and would increase by 1 for each new instance of a particular X. Ultimately, the reason is so that area values (y) for all the objects within a particular ID are stacked above each other over a unique x,z coordinate. This is where I am stuck.
Essentially, I would want the final data frame output given the above input to look like this:

```
ID(x) Area(y)  Z
    3    1.2   1
    3    3.0   1
    3    2.7   1
    2    1.4   1
    2    2.5   1
    3    4.3   2
    3    2.1   2
    3    1.7   2
```

Comment: Souldn't column Z be `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`?

Comment: No, X represents the number of objects with a particular ID and Z represents how many times a given X has shown up. For the first set of 3's, z=1 because that is the first set of 3's. Z is again one when x=2 because that is the first time 2 has shown up.

Comment: @akrun, took care of it, thanks for the tip

Comment: No, it was my mistake when I was clicking to give an upvote. I've tried 1 and 2 on the data sets you came up with and both work well- df2 was an especially good test  by the way. With my data however I keep getting this error: Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column. I'm sure it's not an issue with what you came up with, rather the other complications specific to my dataset.

Comment: @MilesW It may be possible that the column may not present in both the dataset using `merge`.  Please check if there is a leading/lagging space for `ID` in one of the dataset.  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708282/having-a-basic-issue-using-merge-function

Comment: @MilesW If you couldn't figure out the problem, you can update the post with a dput output of small dataset that reproduce the error. ie. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata,20)))`

Comment: got it sorted out now, the link you provided helped, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this in a couple of ways.

**1. base R - aggregate/ave**

We can use `aggregate` to get the length of each elements ('IDx') in 'ID' column, transform the output dataset ('dfN') by creating the 'Z' column based on the duplicate elements in the 'IDx' and 'merge' the 'dfN' with the original dataset 'df1'

```
dfN <- aggregate(cbind(IDx=seq_along(ID))~ID, df1, FUN=length)
dfN$Z <- with(dfN, ave(IDx, IDx, FUN=function(x) cumsum(duplicated(x))+1L))
 merge(df1, dfN, by='ID')[-1]
 #  Area IDx Z
 #1  1.2   3 1
 #2  3.0   3 1
 #3  2.7   3 1
 #4  1.4   2 1
 #5  2.5   2 1
 #6  4.3   3 2
 #7  2.1   3 2
 #8  1.7   3 2
```

**2. base R - ave/rle**

We can create the 'IDx' column with `ave` and then use `rle/inverse.rle' to create the 'Z' column

```
 df1$IDx <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=length))
 v1 <- with(df1, paste0(ID, IDx))
 df1$Z <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(v1), values <-ave(lengths, 
             lengths, FUN=function(x) cumsum(duplicated(x))+1L)))
 df1
 #  ID Area IDx Z
 #1  A  1.2   3 1
 #2  A  3.0   3 1
 #3  A  2.7   3 1
 #4  B  1.4   2 1
 #5  B  2.5   2 1
 #6  C  4.3   3 2
 #7  C  2.1   3 2
 #8  C  1.7   3 2
```

**3. data.table**

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), create the 'IDx' i.e the nrows (`.N`), grouped by 'ID'.  Based on the duplicate elements in 'IDx', we can create the 'Z' column.  Set the key as 'ID' (`setkey`), join with 'df1', and assign the unnecessary column to NULL (`ID:= NULL`)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1)[, list(IDx=.N), by = ID][, IDx1:= IDx][,
     list(ID,Z=cumsum(duplicated(IDx1))+1L) , IDx], ID)[df1][, ID := NULL][]

#   IDx Z Area
#1:   3 1  1.2
#2:   3 1  3.0
#3:   3 1  2.7
#4:   2 1  1.4
#5:   2 1  2.5
#6:   3 2  4.3
#7:   3 2  2.1
#8:   3 2  1.7
```

**4. dplyr**

The idea is similar as above.  Instead of 'merge', we use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, 
            df1 %>% 
              group_by(ID) %>% 
              summarise(IDx=n()) %>% 
              group_by(IDx) %>%
              mutate(Z=cumsum(duplicated(IDx))+1L), by='ID') %>% 
              select(-ID)
 #  Area IDx Z
 #1  1.2   3 1
 #2  3.0   3 1
 #3  2.7   3 1
 #4  1.4   2 1
 #5  2.5   2 1
 #6  4.3   3 2
 #7  2.1   3 2
 #8  1.7   3 2
```

**NOTE:** Tested this with another dataset 'df2'

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
Area = c(1.2, 3, 2.7, 1.4, 2.5, 4.3, 2.1, 1.7)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <-  structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F"), Area = c(1.2, 3, 2.7, 1.4, 2.5, 
4.3, 2.1, 1.7, 1.2, 1.4, 2.1, 1.2, 1.5, 2.3)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```